# Which terminal window app allows for multiple panes and click to open new window

Tags: macos, command-line, software-recommendation

I am watching this screencast series where the guy is using OSX and has this cool terminal window client.

Trying to figure out which one he is using.  Here is a screenshot:

[image]

It looks like he is able to also click on folders and it opens a new terminal window.  Full video is here: https://youtu.be/-kXYycFYDzo?list=PL05JrBw4t0KqoFUiX42JG7BAc7pipMBAy&t=211

Can someone recommend software that performs this based on the screen shot?

Answer (score 5):

[Acme](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Acme_(text_editor)) in Plan9.

There's a [macOS version available](https://code.google.com/archive/p/acme-sac/downloads).

If you want this video Ori actually talks through and explains how to change and edit how the editor behaves: [Plan 9: Not dead, Just Resting, by Ori Bernstein](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6m3GuoaxRNM)

Answer (score 3):

**Like mentioned in my comment (now deleted) this is plan9 running acme:**

The implementation of plan9 actually used in the video is: [Plan 9 from User Space](https://github.com/9fans/plan9port)

It has to be installed/compiled with Xcode:

> **Installation**
>
> To install, run ./INSTALL. It builds mk and then uses mk to run the rest of the installation.
>
> For more details, see install(1), at install.txt in this directory and at https://9fans.github.io/plan9port/man/man1/install.html.

Requirements/Recomendations:

- Xcode 10.1 for High SIerra
- Xcode 11.3 for Mojave (at time of writing)
- the source: https://github.com/9fans/plan9port/archive/master.zip

Example:

[image]

---

Successfully compiled/installed in High Sierra (see screenshot) and Mojave. Not tested in Catalina.